# How to implement TOTP C/S (Time One Time Password Client/Server) in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to create a client/server application using C#, and my application must have the ability to deal with time one time passwords, meaning that my server can authenticate a client after a (TOTP) entry.

I searched over the internet for any example that might be close to something like this or thing but coudln't find anything at all.

Do you happen to have an idea about implementing TOTP, even if its not the same situation I have in here , I just need someone to give me some clues.

Comment: Have you read http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238?

Comment: Good question, http://googleauthcsharp.codeplex.com/ seems to have some implementation, going to try it myself.